# Optimization function with restrictions on its variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Can you please help me to find a continuous function $f(x_1,...,x_n,y)$ which has a global maximum (say, $1$) when at least one of the variables $x_1,...,x_n$ is positive and $y=0$?

Comment: Consider using $max_{k=1}^n min(e^{x_k},1)$

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks, think this will work